# Help with multithreaded Core Data app design

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, core-data, thread-safety

[image]

Above is a simplification of what my model looks like. My app has a `NSWindowController` object controlling two `NSViewController` objects for the **user** and **account** entities. When a user logs in to the app, they can modify user or account information by bringing up the relevant view controller. In the background I have the application periodically populating the user's logs in the application delegate on a separate thread.

I am using a separate `NSManagedObjectContext` for the background thread and the application delegate's `NSManagedObjectContext` for data entry in the view controllers. I would like to know a few things:

1) is this good practice? Should I create a `NSManagedObjectContext` for each view controller and then merge the contexts whenever the user is done making changes?

2) Because the **log** entity is created in the background thread, it has it's own `NSManagedObjectContext`. However, each log includes information from the **user** and **account entities**, which are created in the application delegate's `NSManagedObjectContext`. This is how I am fetching a user:

```
- (NSManagedObjectID*) fetchUser:(NSString*) userID {   
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];   
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"user":inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    /** snip **/
}
```

This method is called by the background thread as follows:

```
NSManagedObjectID* userObjectID = [self fetchUser:userID];
NSManagedObject* userObject = [self.logsManagedObjectContext objectWithID:userObjectID];
```

Is what I'm doing in `fetchUser` thread-safe? Do I need to lock the main managed object context while fetching a user in case one of the views is modifying the same user? From [this article](http://losingfight.com/blog/2006/10/14/core-data-and-multi-threading/) I understand (perhaps incorrectly) that I may have to do so. So far I haven't run into any problems but I don't want to leave a potential edge case.

3)  When one of the view controllers makes changes to the application delegate's `NSManagedObjectContext` it posts a notification that is handled as follows:

```
- (void)contextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification {
    SEL selector = @selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:);
    [self.logManagedObectContext performSelector:selector onThread:backgroundThread withObject:notification waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

Is this how I should handle the merge or should I be merging the application delegate's `NSManagedObjectContext` instead? I found that doing that (on the main thread) locked up the UI.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`NSManagedObjectContext` objects are not thread-safe. This means that if you wish to access Core Data from multiple threads, you will need one for each thread (and created on the thread too). Each of these can use the same `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`, which will serialise access to the persistent store.

This occurs because each `NSManagedObjectContext` **knows how to properly lock the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` when it is in use, avoiding collisions**. By following these rules, you should remain thread-safe.

As you're already doing, `NSManagedObjectID` objects should be used to pass Core Data objects from one MOC to another (and by extension from one thread to another). However you are calling `fetchUser:` which uses the MOC from your main thread, on a background one. This isn't correct. That `fetchUser:` method call must be called from the main thread. Of course, there's nothing to stop you from retrieving the user in the background thread using the background MOC.

In summary, always make calls to an `NSManagedObjectContext` from the thread it was created in.

The trick here is to make sure that both MOCs know about the other's saves, so you must register to receive the notifications from each context. You should then be performing the `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` from the appropriate thread for the MOC. At the moment, your background context is being notified about changes from the main thread's context, but not vice versa.

Oh, and there's no need to have a separate context for each `NSViewController`. As UI elements, their interactions with the context will occur on the same (main) thread, so sharing is fine.

Comment: I didn't know I could just retrieve the user from the background MOC. All I need to do is give them the same **NSPersistentStoreCoordinator**? If I do that do I need to retrieve using Object ID's or can I get the object directly?

Comment: You can get the objects directly. Just be sure to write code to merge changes upon notification from any other MOCs sharing the same coordinator.